# eq(n) and hover()

Tags: jquery

```
$('.rUl li').eq(0).click();
```

Show first item of my news rotator. But with  `$('.rUl li').eq(0).hover();`  the first item not visible. What is the difference between click() and hover() in this issue?
How can I show first item with hover()?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by replace jquery 1.4.4 with 1.4.2

Answer (score 1):

`click()` fires a mouseclick event, while `hover()` fires a mouseover event. These are completely different things.

Answer (score 0):

click() fires when you press the mouse button ( left or right ) while you are on that element.
hover() is a contineous event that fires when are navigating over the element and until you leave